# display student details if absent continuously for 5 days

Tags: php

I have a problem displaying students details who are absent for 5 days continuously. I wrote a `sql` query like :

```
$res = $this->db->findAll("SELECT 
student_id,attn_date,count(is_absent) as absent FROM 
sg_students_attendance where is_absent=1 GROUP BY student_id ORDER BY 
attn_date desc");
```

The condition which I applied is:

```
foreach($res as $rec)
{  

    $abs=$rec['absent'];
    $abs1=5;

    if($abs1==$abs)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$rec['student_id'];
        echo "<td>".$rec['absent'];
        echo "</tr>";
    }

}
```

I am getting students details those who are absent for 5 days but not continuously. What will be the query for that ???

Comment: How is "continuously" defined in your data model?

Comment: I mean 12345... with out getting interrupted like 12467.

Comment: So, in which column is your 1, 2, 3, 4, ... stored?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with PHP code

```
$res=$this->db->findAll("SELECT student_id,attn_date,is_absent as absent FROM sg_students_attendance where is_absent=1 ORDER BY student_id,attn_date desc");
```

PHP code

```
$count = 0;
foreach($res as $rec)
{
     $abs=$rec['absent'];
     if($abs == 1)
         $count++;
     else
         $count = 0;

     if($count == 5)
     {
         echo $rec['student_id'] . ' is absent for continuous 5 or more days<BR>';
         $count = 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer, but I have a problem with while loop.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer, but I have a problem with while loop.
what comes in while loop.

Comment: @KirankumarJala, I use while loop to retrieve the data from the database, so I used while loop. You could use for loop as you are using.